# What are the regular epimorphisms in $\mathrm{hTop}^{\mathrm{connectedCW}}_*$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, cw-complexes, representable-functor

I was wondering how to determine what are the regular epimorphisms (i.e. those which are coequalizers) in $\mathrm{hTop}^{\mathrm{connectedCW}}_*$, the category of pointed connected CW complexes modulo homotopy?

My motivation for asking is that (if I'm not mistaken) these should be sent to monomorphisms by $H^j$ for any reduced generalized Eilenberg-Steenrod cohomology $H^{\bullet}$ and integer $j\geq0$, due to e.g. Brown representability.

Comment: The homotopy category is very poorly behaved from a categorical point of view; I think there should be almost no coequalizers in it. You can see a closely related discussion about pushouts here: https://people.math.binghamton.edu/malkiewich/no_pushout.pdf

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see; thank you for the explanation and reference!